# How to publish MariaDb image to Container registry with pre-seeded data?

Tags: docker, mariadb, digital-ocean

I want to publish a docker image of the development database with seeded data that could be pulled by any team member locally via docker-compose. My reasons to build such an image are:

- have one source of data masking/obfuscation (probably repository responsible for pushing to container registry)
- pull image from the cloud when running API tests
- allow automatic updates of the image (for example in case of DB migration)

I want to use **MariaDB** as the master database and **Digital Ocean** as the container registry.

Does anybody have a working example or can refer to some article/documentation? I struggle to build image with seeded data.

Comment: seed the data outside the container and then copy the mariadb files into the container as part of the docker file

Answer (score 0):

Create the seeded data outside the container and then flash the image with the filesystem directory of the seeded mariadb